# Illegal string offset 'mname' in php?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am having error while retiring data from my database and displaying it to my home page.
Error is like this "Warning: Illegal string offset 'mname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\afe\login\home.php on line 93
h "

Here is my code of starting and saving my data to 
session. I think the problem is here while storing data into sessions

```
session_start(); 
$sqlqqq="select * from mReg where email='$lmail'";
$rr = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlqqq);
$roww = mysqli_fetch_array($rr);

$_SESSION['login_user'] = array();
$_SESSION['login_user']['mname']=$roww[1];
$_SESSION['login_user']['mpic']=$roww[12];
$_SESSION['login_user']['mno']=$roww[5];    
$_SESSION['login_user']['loc']=$roww[7];        
header("location: home.php");
```

And here's my code of displaying it in my home page

```
echo $_SESSION['login_user']['mname'];
```

Comment: No need of `$_SESSION['login_user'] = array();`, Just remove it.

Comment: 1. `$_SESSION['login_user'] = array();` not needed.2. on home page `session_start();` is also required.

Comment: Just make a try as i say, AND remember to start your session at home page as well.

Comment: session_start(); is giving in upper code in my home php. So i it's not the error

Comment: @FrayneKonok Same error received  illegal offset

Comment: @chackers, DID you follow each steps we told you.

Comment: @chackers  on home page write `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_SESSION);` and show us what it prints?

Comment: You can unset your session variable first by using `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);` in your current page before you store new values.

Comment: @anant here is output. Array ( [login_user] => hackingcshah@live.co.uk giving output of my email in database but not what i asked for

Comment: Since your array have no index `mname` so you are getting error

Comment: Thanks @FrayneKonok It's works once i have unset the old session Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps to get solution:

1. You can unset your session variable first by using `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);` in your current page before you store new values.
2. No need of `$_SESSION['login_user'] = array();`
3. start your session in home page as well.